# Can we say something about the number of local maxima of this function ? Can we prove that it has at most $n−1$ local maxima? 

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be the region defined with

$$A = \Big\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid 0 \le x_i < 1\text{ for all $i$, and } \sum x_i < 1 \Big\}.$$

Let $\mathbf{u} =(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ be an arbitrary unit vector with $u_i>0$ for all $i$.

Let $f: A\to \mathbb{R}$ be a multivariate function. And now, define $f_{\mathbf{u}}(t) = f(t\mathbf{u})$. Clearly, this is just the multivariate function $f$ going in the direction of the unit vector $\mathbf{u}$.

Denote as usual with $\mathbf{e}_i$, for some $i=1,\ldots,n$, the basis unit vectors, e.g. $\mathbf{e}_1 = (1,0,\ldots,0)$.

We assume that

1. $f_{\mathbf{u}}'(0) = u_1f_{\mathbf{e}_1}'(0) + \cdots + u_nf_{\mathbf{e}_n}'(0)$, i.e. that the derivative of $f$ at $0$ in any direction is just a linear combination of the derivatives in the basis directions.
2. $f_{\mathbf{u}}''(t) < 0$, i.e. that the derivative $f_{\mathbf{u}}'(t)$ is strictly decreasing. In other words: The slope of $f_{\mathbf{u}}(t)$ is decreasing as $t$ increases.
3. $f_{\mathbf{u}}(t) \to -\infty$ as $t\to 1/\sum u_i$ for any direction $\mathbf{u}$. In other words: In any direction, the multivariate function $f$ approaches minus infinity as the boundary of the region is approached.

**My questions are these:** Can we say something interesting about $f$ in general? In particular: Can we say something about the number of local maxima it has? Can we prove that it has at most $n-1$ local maxima? For $n=2$, it seems intuitively clear that it can have only 1 maximum, and I was wondering whether it would be possible to generalize this to $n$ dimensions.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, Assumption 2 implies that $f$ is strictly concave. Since its domain of definition is convex set, $f$ can have at most one local maximum: otherwise what would happen on the line connecting two maxima?

Comment: Isnt assumption 1 trivial? That's almost the definition of directional derivative

Comment: @LeonidKovalev If $f$ is concave only in each direction, is it necessarily concave in general?

Comment: @leonbloy not quite; directional derivatives could exist and not be given by that formula. The assumed degree of smoothness of $f$ in the question has not been made absolutely clear.

Comment: @meh A function is strictly concave if $f(ta+(1-t)b)>tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$ for all $0<t<1$ and all $a,b$ in the domain of definition. This property holds if and only if it holds on every line -- because it is *defined* in terms of restrictions to lines.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev Yes, but we don't have this result for each line. We only have it for each line going out from the origin. What about all the other lines in the region?

Comment: @LeonidKovalev Also, feel free to just assume that the functions are however smooth we need. Does that validate what leonbloy said?

Comment: @meh Of course, 1 is unnecessary if the function is smooth. To answer the original question: the function can have arbitrarily many local maxima. I'll try to write down an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $n=2$. Pick an integer $m$ and define $f(x_1,x_2)=\sin(m\theta)+g(x_1+x_2)$ where $\theta\in [0,\pi/2]$ is the polar angle of the point $(x_1,x_2)$, the function $g : [0,1)\to\mathbb R$ is strictly concave and satisfies $g(0)=0$, $g(1/2)=1$ (which is the maximum of $g$), and $g(t)\to-\infty$ as $t\to 1$. I will not try to cook up $g$ explicitly, but it can be done without much work. Note that $f$ satisfies all assumptions of the problem.

The absolute maximum of $f$ is equal to $2$ and is attained only at the points where $x_1+x_2=1/2$ and $\theta \in \{\pi/(2m)+2\pi k/m: k\in\mathbb Z\}$. The larger $m$ is, the more such points we have.

$f$ can be smooth near the origin with a slightly more complicated construction. We can make sure that $g'\le -1$ everywhere (all that matters is that $\sup g'<0$). Let $f(x_1,x_2)=\phi(x_1+x_2)\sin(m\theta)+g(x_1+x_2)$ where $\phi$ is a nondecreasing smooth function such that $|\phi''|\le 1/2$ everywhere, $\phi(t)=0$ when $t<1/4$, and $\phi(t)=c>0$ when $t\ge 1/2$. (Informally, it's a smoothened Heaviside function). Now, the global maximum of $f$ is $1+c$ and is attained at the same points as in the first version. Since $\phi$ vanishes for small $t$, there is no problem with $f$ near the origin.

Comment: This function looks somewhat "unstable" near the origin. What if we assume, in addition, that $f(0,\ldots,0) = 0$ and that the $f$ is smooth enough everywhere (including near the origin)? Does that change anything? Intuitively, it seems to me that this would be the case. But how can we confirm it?

Comment: @meh This does not change the matter, see the edited answer. Intuition behind the counterexample: think of the graph of $z=g(x_1+x_2)$ as made of clay. You can create grooves in it by running a finger in the direction away from the origin. If you do it carefully, concavity will be preserved. The grooves will separate the set where $f$ attains its global maximum into many parts.